# @PersistenceUnit does not work in PlayFramework?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, persistence-unit

DB Config:

```
db=mysql://root@localhost/db
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
....
db_other.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2
db_other.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_other.user=root
db_other.pass=
db_other.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

In these databases i have absolutely exact tables (clones).
But the difference is that there's different values in these tables.
('Value #1' and 'Value #2' respectively).

A simple model:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;

@Entity
@PersistenceUnit(name="other")
@Table(name="testtable")
public class DbTest extends GenericModel {
    @Id
    public String value;
}
```

the rest of code:

```
List<DbTest> lst = DbTest.findAll();
if(!lst.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(lst.get(0).value);
```

It always prints Value #1. (It must be 'Value #2' as it's in db2).
Surely, i've specified @PersistenceUnit(name="other").
But that doesn't have any effect. Even if i change name of pers.unit
to random, no any errors.
This annotation is not working or just being ignored?
Or i did mistake somewhere? :/

p.s
Also, i've tried to get the EntityManager as it's shown in the framework manual
(/documentation/jpa#multiple).

```
EntityManager em = JPA.getJPAConfig("other").em();
```

But it's not possible:
<< The method getJPAConfig(String) is undefined for the type JPA >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Play 1.2.3 does not support multiple databases. The Support for
>   multiple databases section was included in this documentation page by
>   mistake (the feature is only in the master branch on github).

(cannot find the source now)

look e.g. here: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/4079cc961db8c750?pli=1

Comment: Really? Oh..very pity.
The documentation is confusing a looot, but anyway thanks.

Comment: By the way! How can i see the documentation? /@documentation/ doesn't work in 2.0

Comment: Not sure what have you meant.But 2.0 is far from full-fledged release.